# How to filter book pages by book with Views? ( how to integrate book with views)

Tags: 9, nodes

At the moment on Drupal 9.3 there is very poor integration between views and Book Module.

how to create a view to show all the book pages with functionality to filter ( an exposed filter)  them by book?

in another word, how to integrate the book module with views to show a list of the book page and filter them ( exposed filter) by book?